# Image resize using Wordpress native class V.S. using AWS Lambda

Tags: wordpress, image, image-processing, aws-lambda

I'm using EC2 + S3 + ELB + CF.

I would like to resize thumbnails before uploading to S3.

In this case,

1) Resize image before uploading to S3(It uses EC2's memory using Wordpress native image editor class WP_Image_Editor instance)

2) Resize image after uploading to S3 using Lambda

Which is better practice do you think?

Thank you for your help :)

Cheers!